# NodeJS Mysql end function stopped working?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

been building a website with a mysql database using the nodejs mysql package.

Stopped working on it for a couple weeks.

With no changes to code, come back and realize that the end function in mysql package appears to no longer be working.

I use an async function like so:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   async function homeResponse(){
       try{
          var db = createConnection();
          await conquerie.connect(db);
            // get stuff from db
          await conquerie.end(db);
       }catch(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.render('error');
       }
   }

   homeResponse();
});
```

conquerie js mentioned above uses:

```
function connect(db){

    let connectpromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        db.connect((err) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('ERROR COULD NOT CONNECT NERD');
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log('Connected to the DB!!!');
            resolve();
        });
    });
    return connectpromise;
}

function end(db){

    let endpromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        db.end((err) =>{
            if(err){
                console.log('cant end connecty');
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log('DB Connection ended!!!');
            resolve();
        });
    });
    return endpromise;

}
```

DB Connect works fine, Info pulls from DB with no issues, end does not work.

It catches an error on db.end and returns 'can't end connecty'.

Connection does not end. If I remove that catch, I get a PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT error.

I have tried async and sync, no change.

Have latest version of mysql package, and no one else online is mentioning this so It's gotta be something I did I guess.

Any Advice is much appreciated. Thanks!~

Comment: What do you mean by "no longer working"? Do you get an error? Is the connection not ended?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying, It catches an error on db.end and returns 'can't end connecty'.

Connection does not end.

If I remove that catch, I get PROTOCOL_SEQUENCE_TIMEOUT error.
Hopefully that helps.


Will update my question with that info.

Comment: check the error.log from mysql,